# Visual Studio: shortcut key equivalent to F2 in Eclipse for option menu

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

What is this popup called in Visual Studio and what is the shortcut key for invoking it? the same menu is invoked by F2 in Eclipse
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu displays SmartTags which can be invoked by pressing Ctrl+.

View.ShowSmartTag  ->    Shift+Alt+F10  or Ctrl+.

Brought from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)